# Creating nonclustered index in productive environment - is cancelling possible if it will take too long?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I want to create some nonclustered indexes in my productive environment. The creation of two were quite fast (about 10 minutes) but one takes 7.30 hours and another 2.30 hours in test environment.

It's not possible to work while the 7.30 hours index will be created because it blocks the table. I've a timeframe of 9 hours in the night. But what is if productive system is slower than test and it wont't be finished in the morning. Can I cancel index creation and the table wont't be blocked and users can work normally? And then I just hit the create query the other night again and it resumes? Or is this dangerous? I don't have enterprise edition, only standard.

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) May 14 2014 18:34:29 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Comment: What version and edition of SQL server do you use? Add results of `SELECT @@Version` to your question.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 Standard

Comment: Yes, you can simply cancel index creation while it is running. As you may know, an index is continuously updated. When you cancel it's creation, it is gone. At least, that is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is resumable online index operations.

Unfortunately, online index operations are not available for the Standard Edition (you need the Enterprise Edition). The resumable ones are available from SQL Server 2017 and higher.

[Resumable Online Index Create and Rebuild Operations](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/resumable-online-index-create-and-rebuild-operations/)

Comment: Ok, does this mean when I cancel the index creation in 2012 sql server it's not resumable but there won't be also any residue which could cause problems? It just can take a while to cancel the operation I've noticed... when it ran 40 minutes it takes 2 minutes to cancel.

Comment: It depends... The transaction will be rolled back and I can't estimate confidently how much time that operation will take. You should try to figure out a cause of so long index creation. For example, if your data file wasn't able to accommodate the new index and had to grow and you have instant file initialisation disabled, time for the index creation operation could increase significantly.